# How do I catch SIGUSR1 in luajit under Linux?

Tags: c, linux, lua, ffi, luajit

I'm wanting to catch SIGINT in luajit. Ultimately I want to be able to capture SIGUSR1.  The intention is to allow me to write logrotate compatable logging where on receipt of SIGUSR1 the logfile is closed and then reopened.

How can I do it using FFI?

Here is what I have so far.

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
local C = ffi.C

local SIG_ERR = -1
local SIGINT  = 1
local SIGUSR1 = 10


ffi.cdef[[
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
]]


local function handler(signo)
   print("caught sig\n")
end

if C.signal(SIGINT, handler) == SIG_ERR then
  print("Can't catch SIGINT\n")
end

while 1 do
end
```

---

Actually, I think there's a couple of things going on here.  I notice you must hit ctrl+c twice and the program exits.  And "caught sig" is not called either time.  I think the C side of the lua interpreter is catching SIGINT already.

So I decided to change SIGINT to SIGUSR1 as that is ultimately what I need.  I notice that it triggers the capture, but I get

```
"PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (bad callback)"
```

It sounds like there is something wrong with the format of my callback function but I'm not sure how to correct that.  Lua is still something quite new to me.

Comment: jit.off(handler) before the handler declaration seems to make it work.  Is this the right thing to be doing?

Comment: Although it crashes on program exit unless I put ffi.cast("sighandler_t", handler) in the call to C.signal(...)

Comment: From memory, I got it working by disabling the jit for the handler function.

Answer (score 8):

It's **NOT** safe to call into the LuaJIT VM from a signal handler if the VM is already actively running code. It doesn't matter whether the Lua code is interpreted or compiled. Signal handlers are called asynchronously and the VM may not be in a consistent state.

You *could* create a second VM (`ffi.C.luaL_newstate()`), set a signal handler to a function in that VM and then somehow communicate between the two VMs. But that's pretty complicated and hard to get right.

I guess it would be easier to use `sigpending()` (periodically check for that, e.g. in the log function) or `signalfd()` (if you already have an event handling loop).